# Refresh listview in Comapct Framework so that it shows the selectedindex?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scroll, compact-framework

I need that selected item make visible in listview 
I tried to use in Form::OnLoad:

```
.Items.Add(lvItem);
....
lvItem.Selected = true;
....
.EnsureVisible(selectedIndex);
.Focus() // Make sure list view focused to allow navigate with hardware cursor keys immediate after form shows
```

This method is not working as I expected:
It only tries to scroll listview. selected item is still not visible, user need to scroll 2 items down.

Is this bug or feature? In FF TopItem property scrolls that item to the top (or attempt to do that)

Compact Framework do not support all versions of every platform for this method.

Is there possible to simulate this property in CF? My be direct API call?

P.S. Second issue: if I try to scroll focused listview with scrollbars selected item prevents.

Scrolling with hardware keys do not prevents previously automatically selected item.

Comment: If I recall correctly, EnsureVisible doesn't correctly take into account the scrollbar.  I think we just called EnsureVisible three times (selectedIndex+1, selectedIndex-1, and selectedIndex) with appropriate bounds checking for first and last item.  Not an Answer because I don't have time at the moment to validate it.

Comment: +2 works. Selected item is now the last visible in listview. As I mentioned,  I should make it always top item (to solve second issue)

Comment: If it works I'll drop it down as an asnwer.  I'm not clear what you are asking for the 2nd issue, can you clarify?

Comment: I can clarify question: the selected item must be always shown on top. If i try to move with cursor keys selection lost and the top item got selected.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `lvItem.Focused = True` as well as `lvItem.Selected = true` and `EnsureVisible` of it?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, EnsureVisible doesn't correctly take into account the scrollbar. I think we just called EnsureVisible three times (selectedIndex+1, selectedIndex-1, and selectedIndex) with appropriate bounds checking for first and last item.